# Is it possible to change the encryption algorithm used by Laravel's default authentication scheme?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, password-hash

Here's the situation: I have a password column stored in plain text and I need to ~encrypt~ hash it. This is fine, but MySql only supports a few types of encryption (AES, Triple-DES, etc) and the native Laravel authentication scheme only uses Blowfish (from php's `hash_password`). I want to migrate the passwords using just native MySQL functions.

Is there any way I can a different hashing algorithm within the default Laravel authentication scheme? I'm really hoping there's a config or something that I could use, but I'm not hopeful after doing a little investigation of the source.

Laravel 5.3

Comment: MySQL's encryption functions are **not suitable for passwords** so please, **do not do this**. Don't use encryption for passwords, use a password-specific hash like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) which Laravel and `password_hash` both sensibly use by default. The team that built Laravel knows what they're doing and they've done a great job of building a safe-by-default authentication system. Don't think you know better because you're only going to break something and expose your users to unnecessary risks.

Comment: Do **NOT** encrypt passwords, **HASH** them.

Comment: Laravel uses `password_hash` for a reason. You shouldn't change this.

Comment: Okay I made a mistake in the way I phrased the question, but these comments are also full of misinformation. `password_hash` does not guarantee security and MySQL does allow for secure *hashing* (sorry) algorithms like SHA512. My point is I want to use a different algorithm than what is default for the default Laravel security, which is in fact an option in later Laravel releases. I regret the way I phrased the question and will fix it, but the comments are also very unhelpful and misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest writing a `console` command to migrate your plain text 
passwords using `PHP`. Laravel has great [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/artisan) on the matter and this should negate trying to reconfigure Laravel's encryption configuration.

> I want to migrate the passwords using just native MySQL functions

Not sure why, unless this is a platform issue. However, you're running Laravel 5.3, so using `PHP` shouldn't be an issue.